# Why does AMCL post-date tf (~transform_tolerance)?

Tags: navigation, transform, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A [comment in the code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L1249-L1278) says

> ```
>     // We want to send a transform that is good up until a
> ```

```
    // tolerance time so that odom can be used
```

And the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Parameters) says

> ~transform_tolerance (double, default: 0.1 seconds)
> Time with which to post-date the transform that is published, to indicate that this transform is valid into the future.

I still don't understand why AMCL needs to pretend to be able to see the future.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218864/why-does-amcl-post-date-tf-(%7Etransform_tolerance)?/) by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1924 on 2015-10-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to understand this for quite some time already, please correct me if I am wrong.

The whole tf tree is as "old" as the oldest tf update from any frame in the entire tree. For example:
odom -> base_link transform updates at frequency of 100hz (encoder + imu), but
map -> odom is only updated with frequency of 10hz (amcl).
Position of the robot in the map frame has update frequency of 10hz (so amcl is the bottleneck).

Now if the amcl algorithm update takes 1s to compute new position, our tf broadcaster will not publish anything for 1s (since it's computing a new update and amcl run in the same loop as tf broadcaster). Therefor we need to stamp map->odom transform "in the future" (aprox as much as it takes for amcl algorithm to calculate new position update).
Otherwise, we would introduce a lag in the system due to this amcl processing time, and map->base_link tf will not be updated.

Am I missing something in my reasoning?
Is there any way to make a map->odom tf always true until new measurement comes in?

---

Originally posted by [Chrisando](https://answers.ros.org/users/28589/chrisando/) with karma: 41 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2018-07-30**:
That could explain it. When looking up the "latest" `map->base_link`, the TF library looks for the latest common time of `map->odom` and `odom->base_link`. So if `map->odom` is old (not future-dated), we don't get the most recent `odom->base_link` in that lookup.

**Comment by [skyofyao@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/40266/skyofyao@gmail.com/) on 2019-10-14**:
Great explanation. One supplement: the assumption to the TF transform `map->odom` is: it's stable, as it shouldn't change much in a short time. So it is OK for the AMCL node to publish such a "predicted" transformation.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-05-05**:
The way to make a transform valid until updated is to use a static transform broadcaster.  The reason AMCL does not use it is unclear to me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-05**:
Most likely because it was not available at the time the AMCL wrapper nodes were written?

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2022-09-14**:
Why didn't they use ros::Time::now() ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [amcl_node.cpp:1380](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/b97780ec5e9b048d756246532b023893538dac69/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L1380) the tf stamp is actually based on the time stamp of the laser scan plus transform_tolerance.
I would say that this transform_tolerance parameter is actually the estimation of AMCL calculation time and have nothing to do with tf availability.

---

Originally posted by [EwingKang](https://answers.ros.org/users/19209/ewingkang/) with karma: 78 on 2018-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2018-07-06**:
Still, as the pose that amcl computes is based on the scan, it is as old as the scan itself. If I have a laser scan at time `t` and need `dt_compute` to compute the pose, that pose should have `t` as stamp and not `t + dt_compute`. The latter would mean AMCL predicts the pose of the future.

**Comment by [EwingKang](https://answers.ros.org/users/19209/ewingkang/) on 2018-07-23**:
@Stephan Ahh now that you've mentioned that,it seems more reasonable :p. Frankly I don't know the exact reason, maybe that is a parameter that loose its function over time. The time stamp of estimation from encoder update doesn't seem to have any problem and does not involve that param.